# How can I print the trash value as the correct value?

Tags: c++

I pressed 1 and entered information related to students. Then press 2 to get the calculations that fit the information I entered, but the trash values come out.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

struct Subject {    //과목 정보
    char Subname[30];      //과목이름
    int Hakjum;            //과목학점
    char Grade[10];        //과목등급
    float GPA;             //과목평점
};

struct Student {    //학생정보
    char StdName[30];      //학생이름
    int Hakbun;            //학번
    Subject Sub[3];        //과목
    float AveGPA;          //교과목 평균 평점
};

int main()
{
    cout.precision(2);
    cout << fixed;

    int n = 0;
    struct Student Stu[10];  //구조체변수 선언

    while (n < 3)                               //반복문을 통해 1또는 2를 눌렀을 때 메뉴판으로 돌아오기
    {
        cout << "===== 메뉴 =====\n";            //메뉴판
        cout << "1. 학생 성적 입력\n";
        cout << "2. 전체 학생 성적 보기\n";
        cout << "3. 프로그램 종료\n";
        cout << "\n";
        cout << "원하는 기능을 입력하세요 : ";
        cin >> n;


        if (n <= 1) {                            //1번 선택하였을 경우
            for (int t = 0; t <= 1; t++)
            {
                cout << "*" << t + 1 << " 번째 학생 이름과 학번을 입력하세요.\n";     //이름과 학번을 입력 받음
                cout << "이름 : ";
                cin >> Stu[t].StdName;
                cout << "학번 : ";
                cin >> Stu[t].Hakbun;
                cout << "\n";
                cout << "\n";
                cout << "* 수강한 과목3개와 각 교과목명, 과목학점, 과목등급을 입력하세요.\n";     //과목과, 학점, 등급을 입력받음
                for (int a = 0; a < 3; a++)
                {
                    cout << "교과목명 : ";
                    cin >> Stu[t].Sub[a].Subname;
                    cout << "과목학점수 : ";
                    cin >> Stu[t].Sub[a].Hakjum;
                    cout << "과목등급<A+ ~ F> : ";
                    cin >> Stu[t].Sub[a].Grade;

                    cout << "\n";

                }
                cout << "\n\n\n";
            }


        }

        else if (n <= 2) {                                              //2번 선택하였을 경우
            cout << "\n\t\t전체 학생 성적 보기\n";
            cout << "===================================================================\n";
            for (int t = 0; t <= 1; t++) {
                cout << "이름 : " << Stu[t].StdName << "\t학번 : " << Stu[t].Hakbun << "\n";          //학생의 개인정보 출력
                cout << "===================================================================\n";
                cout << "\t\t과목명 \t    과목학점 \t과목등급 \t과목평점\n";
                cout << "===================================================================\n";
                for (int a = 0; a < 3; a++) {                                   //문자열 비교 연산자를 사용하여 등급을 평점으로 바꿈

                    if (Stu[t].Sub[a].Grade, "A+" == 0) {
                        Stu[t].Sub[a].GPA = 4.5 * Stu[t].Sub[a].Hakjum;
                    }

                    else if (Stu[t].Sub[a].Grade, "A0" == 0) {
                        Stu[t].Sub[a].GPA = 4.0 * Stu[t].Sub[a].Hakjum;
                    }

                    else if (Stu[t].Sub[a].Grade, "B+" == 0) {
                        Stu[t].Sub[a].GPA = 3.5 * Stu[t].Sub[a].Hakjum;
                    }

                    else if (Stu[t].Sub[a].Grade, "B0" == 0) {
                        Stu[t].Sub[a].GPA = 3.0 * Stu[t].Sub[a].Hakjum;
                    }

                    else if (Stu[t].Sub[a].Grade, "C+" == 0) {
                        Stu[t].Sub[a].GPA = 2.5 * Stu[t].Sub[a].Hakjum;
                    }

                    else if (Stu[t].Sub[a].Grade, "C0" == 0) {
                        Stu[t].Sub[a].GPA = 2.0 * Stu[t].Sub[a].Hakjum;
                    }

                    else if (Stu[t].Sub[a].Grade, "D+" == 0) {
                        Stu[t].Sub[a].GPA = 1.5 * Stu[t].Sub[a].Hakjum;
                    }

                    else if (Stu[t].Sub[a].Grade, "D0" == 0) {
                        Stu[t].Sub[a].GPA = 1.0 * Stu[t].Sub[a].Hakjum;
                    }

                    else if (Stu[t].Sub[a].Grade, "F" == 0) {
                        Stu[t].Sub[a].GPA = 0.0 * Stu[t].Sub[a].Hakjum;
                    }

                    Stu[t].AveGPA = (Stu[t].Sub[0].GPA + Stu[t].Sub[1].GPA + Stu[t].Sub[2].GPA) / (Stu[t].Sub[0].Hakjum + Stu[t].Sub[1].Hakjum + Stu[t].Sub[2].Hakjum);    //평균 평점을 구함


                    cout << "\t\t" << Stu[t].Sub[a].Subname << "\t\t" << Stu[t].Sub[a].Hakjum << "\t   " << Stu[t].Sub[a].Grade << "\t\t   " << Stu[t].Sub[a].GPA << "\n";  //과목명, 과목학점, 과목등급, 과목평점 출력
                }
                cout << "===================================================================\n";
                cout << "\t\t\t\t평균평점\t" << Stu[t].AveGPA << "\n\n";
            }
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

**The output**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zljDr.png)

I get a trash value in the "subject grade".

**Expected**

I want it to be calculated according to the number I enter.

I hope the "과목평점" is right.

Comment: `if (Stu[t].Sub[a].Grade, "A+" == 0)` Those conditionals look very wrong. Are you missing a `strcmp` in those?

Comment: Why are you using C strings in C++ anyway? Course requirement? Because that's generally... a bad sign. Using C strings in C++ is rather advanced subject (by which I mean, it's not done unless there is some quite specific reason).

Answer (score 0):

This is garbage:

```
                if (Stu[t].Sub[a].Grade, "A+" == 0) {
```

What it does is use comma operator. So first it will get `Stu[t].Sub[a].Grade` and... do nothing with it. Then it will get `"A+" == 0`, which is comparing string literal (`const char*` pointer) to 0, which is same as `nullptr`, which is false because string literal is not going to be `nullptr`. So this condition is always false. It's the last experssion with the comman operator, so this `false` result will be used for the `if`. Same for the rest of them.

---

It should be

```
                if (std::strcmp(Stu[t].Sub[a].Grade, "A+") == 0) {
```

The function `std::strcmp` is declared in `cstring` header, which you already have included, and since you have `using namespace std` there, you can leave the `std::` out if you feel confident you know `std::` namespace functions well enough.